# How to portably module qualify powershell cmdlet name between windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to work on both Windows and Linux.  AFAICT a module qualified name requires a '\' (backslash) under windows and a '/' (forward slash) under Linux.

For example:

`ModuleName\CmdletName`            <-------- this works on Windows, fails on Linux

`ModuleName/CmdletName`            <-------- this works on Linux, fails on Windows

How can I write this code to work in both environments?

Comment: `& (Get-Command ModuleName\CmdletName)` might do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  That seems to work, unchanged, on both Windows and Linux.  It requires the '\' (backslash) as a delimiter. (Edited because I misinterpreted my own results earlier)